# How can I create time in proper format to export to a netCDF file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, netcdf, netcdf4

## Data

I am trying to create a time dimension using this:

```
t1 = datetime(1901,1,1);
t2 = datetime(2016,12,31);
t = t1:t2;
```

And create a netCDF file using this

```
nccreate('prec.nc','Prec',...
    'Dimensions',{'time' 42369 'lon' 135 'lat' 129},...
    'Format', 'netcdf4');
```

## What I have tried

ncwrite('prec.nc', 'time', t);

## Error Message

```
Error using cast
Unsupported data type for conversion: 'datetime'.

Error in internal.matlab.imagesci.nc/write (line 778)
                    scale_factor = cast(1, class(varData));

Error in ncwrite (line 87)
ncObj.write(varName, varData, start, stride);
```

## Question

How can I create a daily time dimension that I can write out to a netCDF file? What is the proper date type for this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

NetCDF doesn't define a single native way of storing date/time values, but there are established conventions, [as desribed here](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/BestPractices.html#bp_Calendar-Date-Time).

> There are two strategies for storing a date/time into a netCDF variable. One is to encode it as a numeric value and a unit that includes the reference time, e.g. "seconds since 2001-1-1 0:0:0" or "days since 2001-1-1 0:0:0" . The other is to store it as a String using a standard encoding and Calendar. The former is more compact if you have more than one date, and makes it easier to compute intervals between two dates.

So you could:

a) Use `datestr` to convert it to a string value. The conventional date string format for data interchange is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which you can get in Matlab with `datestr(myDateTime, 'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS')`.

b) Convert it to a numeric value representing seconds or days since a reference "epoch" time. I'd suggest using the Unix epoch, since Matlab provides a convenient conversion function for this already: `posixtime(myDateTime)`. Then specify your units for that variable in the NetCDF file as `'seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00'`.

You probably want to make sure your datetimes are in UTC before encoding them in the NetCDF, so you don't have to worry about time zone issues.